# Collider inside another collider: Move the brain via mouse while being able the click the spheres

Tags: unity, collider, intersection, occlusion

[image]

The spheres have a sphere collider on them and are clickable via this script:`Clickable.cs`

```
public class Clickable : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update()
    {
         ClickDetect();    
    }

    void ClickDetect()
    {

        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);       

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Transform t = hit.collider.transform;
          
            if (t.name == "Sphere(Clone)")
            {                 
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {                       
                        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.7f);

                    Debug.Log(t.parent.name + (t.GetSiblingIndex() + 1));
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the brain has a box collider on it and is moved by this script `RotateonMouse`

```
void Rotation()
{
    if (_isRotating)
    {
        // offset
        _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference);

        // apply rotation
        _rotation.y = -(_mouseOffset.x) * _sensitivity;
        _rotation.x = -(_mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity;

        // rotate
        transform.eulerAngles += _rotation;

        // store mouse
        _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```

The issue arises when I try to click on the spheres when the box collider on the brain is on.

I end up rotating the brain instead of being able to click the spheres.
Is there a way to be able to click inside the collider while also on the collider to rotate the brain?

Comment: Have you considered using a LayerMask to make your Raycast interact solely with the spheres, and ignore the layer used by the brain's collider? Or using RaycastAll to get raycast hits beyond the first?

Comment: If this solution worked for you (judging from your latest post), please share your solution as an Answer below, and mark the Answer Accepted by clicking on the green checkmark after the required waiting period.